# jedi:goto-definition overjumping the import section

Tags: elpy

I am using `jedi:goto-definition` to jump to function definitions.

If the function has a definiton under `import` it first jumps into that and I have to do second jump to the module again. Can it directly jump to the module by over passing the import jump?

---

Here: cursor is on top of `my_function`. When I do `jedi:goto-definition` it first jumps to `my_function,` under import at the top of the file. Than when I do `jedi:goto-definition` it jump to its definition.

```
from utils import (                      |
    my_function, <-----| --------------> |  def my_function(arg):
    _log               |                 |      ....
)                      |                 |
                       |                 |
my_function("hello") --| # cursor is here
```

wanted behavior:

```
my_function("hello") --| # cursor is here ----> | def my_function(arg):
```

---

setup:

```
(defun my/python-mode-hook ()
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-jedi))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my/python-mode-hook)
(company-jedi 1)

(setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi")
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)

(global-set-key "\C-x\C-j" 'jedi:goto-definition)
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-k" 'jedi:goto-definition-pop-marker)
```